# How to return object after vector.push_back(std::move(Object))?

Tags: c++, templates, move

I have an Entity which has this piece of code:

```
std::vector<Component*> Components;

template<typename T, typename... TArgs>
T& AddComponent(TArgs&&... args)
{
    T* component = new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    
    Components.push_back(std::move(component));
    
    return Components.back();
}
```

The questions are:

1. Is the component guaranteed to be moved and added?
2. Will the reference to the returned object be valid?
3. Are there any additional checks necessary for this function (in your opinion)?

Comment: vector of pointers? Already a bit fishy... raw use of new? Now quite fishy.

Comment: @einpoklum Vector of pointers fishy? What about polymorphism?

Comment: `back()` would return pointer... You probably want `return *Components.back();`.

Comment: Making rvalue from objects of basic types, such as a pointer here, does not make any difference.

Comment: `std::move`ing a pointer is ... just a copy.

Comment: @DanielLangr: reference to pointer (`Component*&`), not `Component&`, as we have a `vector<Component*>`.

Comment: and casting would be needed to keep dynamic type.

Comment: 1. nothing is moved and nothing should be moved. you use the pointer, it won't copy.  2. yes, but maybe you should return `*Components.back()`. 3. no, but you may should think of carefully the lifetime of your component. why not use `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: see ++17 implementation of emplace_back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the component guaranteed to be moved and added?

No, because you're "moving" the pointer. And allocations don't get "moved" like that. In fact, there's no reason for you to `std::move()` if you're using a pointer anyway.

Also, Like @rustyx suggested, you probably want to use `std::unique_ptr<Component>` rather than `Component*`, as that will take care of deallocating the memory when the vector is destroyed.

> Will the reference to the returned object be valid?

Yes, but it may become invalid if you add another component. Remember that `back()` will not give you a `Component*`, but rather a `Component*&`.

So what you probably want to return is actually `*component`.

> Are there any additional checks necessary for this function (in your opinion)?

Other than the above - seriously consider avoiding the vector of pointers in favor of something else. dynamic polymorphism is out of fashion :-P ... have you considered variants?

---

Putting things together:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename... TArgs>
T& addComponent(TArgs&&... args)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value,
       "Trying to add a 'component' whose type does not inherit Component");
    T* component = new T(std::forward<TArgs>(args)...);
    Components.emplace_back(static_cast<Component*>(component));
    return *component;
}

// ...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everything is more or less clear. In principle, I incorrectly considered the usage of move semantics in this case.
Cannot understand this line: Components.emplace_back(static_cast<Component*>(component)); // is that implicitly constructs unique_ptr? Why we using casting here?

Comment: @Anton it explicitly calls constructor `unique_ptr(Component*)`. casting is actually unnecessary.

Comment: @Anton: RedFog is correct: emplace_back will construct an element in-pace, and in our case the elements are `std::unique_ptr<Component>`'s. I made the cast explicit to better satisfy the [principle of least astonishment](https://wiki.c2.com/?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment).